# Insert new row following calculation, and loop it for multiple subjects

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, apply

This feels like a basic question for I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I want to insert a new row in my data frame after performing a calculation, and then loop that procedure (calculation & inserting row with output) for each participant I have.

My data frame looks something like this (with 9 subjects total), where I have 8 pre-post treatment outcomes per subject:

```
| subID | treatment                    | outcome |
| ----- | ---------------------------- | ------- |
| 14325 | affected_pre_1               | 0.45    |
| 14325 | affected_pre_2               | 0.25    |
| 14325 | unaffected_pre_1             | 1.05    |
| 14325 | unaffected_pre_2             | 1.23    |
| 14325 | affected_post_1              | 0.22    |
| 14325 | affected_post_2              | 0.45    |
| 14325 | unaffected_post_1            | 0.87    |
| 14325 | unaffected_post_2            | 0.34    |
| 18964 | affected_pre_1               | 0.90    |
| 18964 | affected_pre_2               | 1.13    |
| 18964 | unaffected_pre_1             | 0.55    |
| 18964 | unaffected_pre_2             | 0.23    |
| 18964 | affected_post_1              | 0.17    |
| 18964 | affected_post_2              | 1.22    |
| 18964 | unaffected_post_1            | 1.89    |
| 18964 | unaffected_post_2            | 0.76    |
| 39274 | affected_pre_1               | 0.88    |
| 39274 | affected_pre_2               | 0.12    |
| 39274 | unaffected_pre_1             | 0.05    |
| 39274 | unaffected_pre_2             | 0.34    |
| 39274 | affected_post_1              | 0.99    |
| 39274 | affected_post_2              | 0.32    |
| 39274 | unaffected_post_1            | 1.81    |
| 39274 | unaffected_post_2            | 1.34    |
|  ...  | ...                          | ...     |
```

I want to create 4 new rows for each subject with the following calculation (essentially normalizing some of the measures):

```
row 1 = affected_pre_2 / affected_pre_1
row 2 = unaffected_pre_2 / unaffected_pre_1
row 3 = affected_post_2 / affected_post_1
row 4 = unaffected_post_2 / unaffected_post_1
```

Based on a previous answer, I've tried the following:

```
data %>%
bind_rows(data %>% summarise(subID = str_c(subID, lead(subID), sep = '_')) %>% na.omit() %>%
bind_cols(data %>% summarise(across(5:11, ~ . - lead(.))) %>% na.omit()))
```

The across(5:11 ...) refers to the multiple outcome variables I have (in my example dataset, I just included one outcome variable for simplicity).

However, i got a warming that summarise() was deprecated - is there a better way to do this?

I *think* I might also need to use the apply function somewhere in there, but I'm not sure how to loop everything through each subject then. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a pivot/mutate/pivot should work well here:

```r
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
pivot_wider(quux, subID, names_from = treatment, values_from = outcome) %>%
  transmute(
    subID, 
    row1 = affected_pre_2 / affected_pre_1, 
    row2 = unaffected_pre_2 / unaffected_pre_1, 
    row3 = affected_post_2 / affected_post_1, 
    row4 = unaffected_post_2 / unaffected_post_1
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-subID, names_to = "treatment", values_to = "outcome")
# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    subID treatment outcome
#    <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#  1 14325 row1        0.556
#  2 14325 row2        1.17 
#  3 14325 row3        2.05 
#  4 14325 row4        0.391
#  5 18964 row1        1.26 
#  6 18964 row2        0.418
#  7 18964 row3        7.18 
#  8 18964 row4        0.402
#  9 39274 row1        0.136
# 10 39274 row2        6.8  
# 11 39274 row3        0.323
# 12 39274 row4        0.740
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I am getting the following error: 

In argument: `affected_pre = (affected_pre_2/affected_pre_1)`.
Caused by error in `affected_pre_2 / affected_pre_1`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator

The outcome values based on class(df$outcome) is numeric so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: That suggests that your `outcome` is not numeric. Use `as.numeric` to fix that.

Comment: Thanks very much - the problem was that somehow my df had a few fully NA rows that were added in. Not sure how that happened, but I deleted them and this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subID, row =as.integer(gl(n(),2,n()))) %>% 
  transmute(x = last(outcome)/first(outcome)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  group_by(subID) %>% 
  mutate(row = paste0("row", row_number()))
```

```
   subID row       x
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1 14325 row1  0.556
 2 14325 row2  1.17 
 3 14325 row3  2.05 
 4 14325 row4  0.391
 5 18964 row1  1.26 
 6 18964 row2  0.418
 7 18964 row3  7.18 
 8 18964 row4  0.402
 9 39274 row1  0.136
10 39274 row2  6.8  
11 39274 row3  0.323
12 39274 row4  0.740
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Both this and r2evans' response work great. The reason I went with the other response as the solution is because it had a simple way of renaming the added rows to whatever I want. Otherwise, both solutions were very helpful.